# Index.cond does not rearrange the panels in lattice

Tags: r, graphics, lattice

I am following the book "R in action" P389 example to arrange hist panels in the following lattice graph:

```
library(lattice)
graph1 <- histogram(~ height | voice.part, data = singer,
                    main = "Heights of Choral Singers by Voice Part")
graph2 <- densityplot(~ height, data = singer, group = voice.part,
                      plot.points = FALSE, auto.key = list(columns = 4))
plot(graph1, position=c(0, .3, 1, 1))
plot(graph2, position=c(0, 0, 1, .3), newpage = FALSE)
```

As instruction from the book, I use `index.cond` to change the order of the graph, like

```
plot(graph1, position = c(0, .3, 1, 1),
     index.cond = list(c(2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7)))
```

But the order in the graph does not change. Can anyone help me of this?
I also notice `index.cond` is not in the help of `?plot`

Comment: "index.cond" seems to be an argument for `?update.trellis` -- `update(graph1, position = c(0, .3, 1, 1), index.cond = list(c(2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7)))`

Comment: Really thanks. That solves my question perfectly.

Comment: @alexis_laz: That seems worthy of a "real" answer. Handling lattice panel arguments can be tricky and I don't remember seeing this solution described on SO or Rhelp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"index.cond", as other arguments described in `?xyplot` are either passed to the functions that create "trellis" objects or to the `update` methods. So, in this case, you can

create "graph1" by passing "index.cond" to `histogram`:

```
histogram(~ height | voice.part, data = singer, 
          main = "Heights of Choral Singers by Voice Part", 
          index.cond = list(c(2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7)))
```

, use `update`:

```
update(graph1, index.cond = list(c(2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7)))
```

or use `"["`:

```
graph1[c(2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7)]
```